# Converting coordinate entries from East and West to positive and negative

Tags: r, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I currently have a data set listed as

```
Latitude     Longitude
lat:51.40    long:2.19W
lat:50.52    long:1.09E
lat:57.54    long:3.06W
```

How do I remove the W and E and make the W reading a negative in Rstudio?

after running dput(head(df)) as comment below suggested (the first few entries in the data set are errors so lat and long values were recorded as 0).

structure(list(latitude = c("        deg_latitude: 0", "        deg_latitude: 0",
"        deg_latitude: 0", "        deg_latitude: 0", "        deg_latitude: 0",
"        deg_latitude: 0", "        deg_latitude: 0", "        deg_latitude: 0",
"        deg_latitude: 0", "        deg_latitude: 0", "        deg_latitude: 0",
"        deg_latitude: 0", "        deg_latitude: 0", "        deg_latitude: 0",
"        deg_latitude: 0", "        deg_latitude: 0", "        deg_latitude: 0",
"        deg_latitude: 0", "        deg_latitude: 56.3600006103516",
"        deg_latitude: 56.3400001525879"), longitude = c("        deg_longitude: 0.0",
"        deg_longitude: 0.0", "        deg_longitude: 0.0", "        deg_longitude: 0.0",
"        deg_longitude: 0.0", "        deg_longitude: 0.0", "        deg_longitude: 0.0",
"        deg_longitude: 0.0", "        deg_longitude: 0.0", "        deg_longitude: 0.0",
"        deg_longitude: 0.0", "        deg_longitude: 0.0", "        deg_longitude: 0.0",
"        deg_longitude: 0.0", "        deg_longitude: 0.0", "        deg_longitude: 0.0",
"        deg_longitude: 0.0", "        deg_longitude: 0.0", "        deg_longitude: 3.38000011444092W",
"        deg_longitude: 3.36999988555908W")), row.names = c(NA,
20L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello Alice, welcome to stack overflow.  What have you tried so far?  It's also useful to have a reproducible example - if you can run `dput(head(df))` (where df if your data frame) and then post the results into your original question (not a comment) then people will be able to work on the problem with you.

Comment: Typically the first few rows with actual info would be more useful, but see if Tom's answer below solves the issue first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all characters that is not digits and punctuation, and if "W" is detected (`str_detect()`) turn the value to negative

```
library(tidyverse) 

df %>%
  mutate(across(
    everything(),
    ~ case_when(
      str_detect(., "W") ~ as.numeric(str_remove_all(., "[^0-9\\.]")) * -1,
      TRUE ~ as.numeric(str_remove_all(., "[^0-9\\.]"))
    )
  ))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Latitude Longitude
     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     51.4     -2.19
2     50.5      1.09
3     57.5     -3.06
```

EDIT:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(
    everything(),
    ~ case_when(
      str_detect(., "W") ~ str_c("-", str_remove_all(., "[^0-9\\.]")),
      TRUE ~ str_remove_all(., "[^0-9\\.]"
    )
  )))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tom! I would not have been able to solve that problem without your help :) Your coding worked perfectly

Comment: Hi @Tom, thanks again for your help. I just realised that this code rounds everything to 2d.p Is there a way to avoid this as some of the coordinates are longer than that?

Comment: @Jane Hi, please look at my edit. It does not seem to round it to 2 decimals for me. If it is an issues, please edit your post and add the output of dput(head(df, 10)) so I can see the data properly.

Comment: have I done that correctly?

Comment: @Jane Hi Jane, the new code now does not round the number and but it is in character format.

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
library(readr)
DT <- fread("Latitude     Longitude
lat:51.40    long:2.19W
lat:50.52    long:1.09E
lat:57.54    long:3.06W")

DT[, c("deg_lat", "deg_lon") := lapply(.SD, readr::parse_number)]
DT[grepl(".*W$", Longitude), deg_lon := -1 * deg_lon]

    Latitude  Longitude deg_lat deg_lon
1: lat:51.40 long:2.19W   51.40   -2.19
2: lat:50.52 long:1.09E   50.52    1.09
3: lat:57.54 long:3.06W   57.54   -3.06
```